# Comparison of negative binomial models using cross validation

Tags: statistical-significance, cross-validation, negative-binomial-distribution, model-evaluation

I would like to compare several negative binomial models 2 by 2. Some tests will be between two nested models. Some others will be between overlapping  models but not nested.
To do the different models, I'm using a 10 fold cross validation process to get more robust results in a context of academic research.

So how could I do these comparisons ?

For nested models, I think to use loglikelihood ratio test. I would sum the loglihelihood coming from all tests set of the reduced model and also the same sum from the 10 "full" models.
The difference of the first  by the second multiplied by -2 could be compared to a Chi-square with df=10*nb parameters as each of the 10 individual tests follows a Chi-square with df=nb parameters under the null hypothesis.

For overlapping models, I think to use Vuong tests but it seems more tricky to combine the cross-validation results.

I have also looked at AIC, AICC and BIC metrics, but I'm not interested to use them as it is difficult to interpret the result (we can only say the lower the better) and there's also the issue to combine it with cross-validation.

Any idea? There are may be also other methods that the one's I mention.